# Elasticbeanstalk How to authorize to create load balancer?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my Django project into eb. But this error happened when I create the environment.

> ERROR   Creating load balancer failed Reason: API: elasticloadbalancing:CreateLoadBalancer User: is not authorized to perform: iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole on resource role/aws-service-role/elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForElasticLoadBalancing

I'm doing with IAM user so I need to add permissions manually. But I don't know the permission to do this. 
Which permissions do I need to add to deploy and manage project comfortably?

Currently I just added `AWSS3FullAccess` and `AWSElasticbeanstalkFullAccess`.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/elb-api-permissions.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.